# Using sed with regex to match varying lines

Tags: linux, sed, command

I'm having some issues used sed to match a regex pattern. An example would be with the following lines:

spring-core-4.0.0 should be spring-core-4.1.0

spring-web-4.0.0  should be spring-web-4.1.0

I want the regex to match any characters in between spring and the version number. I'm not sure if I need to do something else for sed to remember what those characters are in each line.

```
sed -E 's/spring-([a-z]+)-4.0.0/spring-([a-z]+)-4.1.0/' file.txt
```

The current output is placing the regex pattern in the output, instead of matching it. Thanks for any tips.

Comment: `sed 's/spring-\([a-z]\+\)-4\.0\.0/spring-\1-4.1.0/' file.txt` ???

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ sed 's/\(spring-[^-]*-\)4.0.0/\14.1.0/' file
spring-core-4.1.0
spring-web-4.1.0
```